# The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this

Tags: .net, wpf, sta

I know, there are a lot of similar questions on SO. But I have pretty strange situation: I get this exception while it is executed inside Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke. I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my StackTrace (you can see dispatcher is called there):

> ```
>    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager..ctor()
>    at
> ```
>
> System.Windows.Input.InputManager.GetCurrentInputManagerImpl()
>          at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation..ctor()
>          at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FrameworkServices..ctor()
>          at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EnsureFrameworkServices()
>          at System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor()
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Control..ctor()
>          at System.Windows.Controls.UserControl..ctor()
>          at
>   MCC.PresentationUtilities.ClosingAwareViewModelUserControl..ctor()
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.PatientDetailUI.Views.PatientDetailView..ctor()
>   in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.PatientDetailUI\Views\PatientDetailView.xaml.cs:line
>   11
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.MultipleViewHost.Managers.TabItemFactory.PatientTabItemFactory.CreateEditableView(PatientDetailViewModel
>   vm) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.MultipleViewHost\Managers\TabItemFactory\PatientTabItemFactory.cs:line
>   41
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.MultipleViewHost.Managers.TabItemFactory.PatientTabItemFactory.Create(SelectedPatientChangedEventArgs
>   patient, IClosableController& controller) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.MultipleViewHost\Managers\TabItemFactory\PatientTabItemFactory.cs:line
>   31
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.MultipleViewHost.Managers.PatientEventsManager.CreateNewPatientTab(SelectedPatientChangedEventArgs
>   patientInfo) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.MultipleViewHost\Managers\PatientEventsManager.cs:line
>   94
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.MultipleViewHost.Managers.PatientEventsManager.AddPatientView(SelectedPatientChangedEventArgs
>   patientInfo) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.MultipleViewHost\Managers\PatientEventsManager.cs:line
>   75
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.MultipleViewHost.Managers.PatientEventsManager.DataImportFinishedHandler(DataImportFinishedEventArgs
>   dataImportFinishedEventArgs) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.MultipleViewHost\Managers\PatientEventsManager.cs:line
>   41
>          at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Events.EventSubscription`1.InvokeAction(Action`1
>   action, TPayload argument) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.Definitions\Prism\EventSubscription.cs:line
>   122
>          at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Events.EventSubscription`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<GetExecutionStrategy>b__0(Object[]
>   arguments) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.Definitions\Prism\EventSubscription.cs:line
>   108
>          at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Events.EventBase.InternalPublish(Object[]
>   arguments) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.Definitions\Prism\EventBase.cs:line
>   69
>          at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Events.CompositePresentationEvent`1.Publish(TPayload
>   payload) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.Definitions\Prism\CompositePresentationEvent.cs:line
>   168
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager.DataRecordManager.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4()
>   in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager\DataRecordManager.cs:line
>   247
>          at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>          at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>          at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object
>   userData)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
>          at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr
>   wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>          at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>          at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Delegate method,
>   Object[] args)
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager.DataRecordManager.DataImportedIntoDb(Patient
>   patient, DetectedDevice detectedDevice, DataRecord dataRecord) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager\DataRecordManager.cs:line
>   247
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager.DataRecordManager.Process(DetectedDeviceInfo
>   detectedDeviceInfo) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager\DataRecordManager.cs:line
>   66
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager.DeviceToDatabaseSaverManager.CreateOrUpdateDeviceEntity(IDeviceDataInfo
>   deviceDataInfo) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager\DeviceToDatabaseSaverManager.cs:line
>   106
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager.DeviceToDatabaseSaverManager.FoundDevice(IDeviceDataInfo
>   deviceDataInfo) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager\DeviceToDatabaseSaverManager.cs:line
>   88
>          at
>   MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager.DeviceToDatabaseSaverManager.DeviceDetectedHandler(Object
>   sender, DetectedDeviceInfoEventArgs e) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.TherapyDeviceManager.DeviceManager\DeviceToDatabaseSaverManager.cs:line
>   70
>          at
>   MCC.Devices.DeviceDetection.ConnectionManagers.ConnectionManagerAggregator.OnDeviceDetected(DetectedDeviceInfoEventArgs
>   e) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.Devices.DetectService\ConnectionManagers\ConnectionManagerAggregator.cs:line
>   22
>          at
>   MCC.Devices.DeviceDetection.ConnectionManagers.ConnectionManagerAggregator.DeviceDetectedHandler(Object
>   sender, DetectedDeviceInfoEventArgs e) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.Devices.DetectService\ConnectionManagers\ConnectionManagerAggregator.cs:line
>   58
>          at
>   MCC.Devices.DeviceDetection.ConnectionManagers.SpecificConnectionManagerBase`2.OnDeviceDetected(DetectedDeviceInfoEventArgs
>   e) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.Devices.DetectService\ConnectionManagers\SpecificConnectionManagerBase.cs:line
>   33
>          at
>   MCC.Devices.DeviceDetection.ConnectionManagers.SpecificConnectionManagerBase`2.AddDevice(TConnection
>   connection, DeviceData device) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.Devices.DetectService\ConnectionManagers\SpecificConnectionManagerBase.cs:line
>   258
>          at
>   MCC.Devices.DeviceDetection.ConnectionManagers.SpecificConnectionManagerBase`2.FoundDevice(TConnection
>   connection, DeviceData newlyDetectedDevice) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.Devices.DetectService\ConnectionManagers\SpecificConnectionManagerBase.cs:line
>   229
>          at
>   MCC.Devices.DeviceDetection.ConnectionManagers.SpecificConnectionManagerBase`2.DetectDeviceOnAquiredConnection(TConnection
>   connection) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.Devices.DetectService\ConnectionManagers\SpecificConnectionManagerBase.cs:line
>   185
>          at
>   MCC.Devices.DeviceDetection.ConnectionManagers.SpecificConnectionManagerBase`2.Poll(TConnection
>   connection) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.Devices.DetectService\ConnectionManagers\SpecificConnectionManagerBase.cs:line
>   166
>          at
>   MCC.Devices.DeviceDetection.ConnectionManagers.Managers.SdConnectionManager.Poll(FileConnection
>   connection) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.Devices.DetectService\ConnectionManagers\Managers\SdConnectionManager.cs:line
>   51
>          at
>   MCC.Devices.DeviceDetection.ConnectionManagers.SpecificConnectionManagerBase`2.PollingCycle(Object
>   tokenObject, TConnectionMetadata detectedConnectionMetadata) in
>   D:\WTS\WTS3\WTS\MCC.Devices.DetectService\ConnectionManagers\SpecificConnectionManagerBase.cs:line
>   142

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a thread other than the main thread, using `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` will keep the code executing in your current thread, it won't move it to the main thread. And you can't create UI components (like controls) on other threads.

What you should do is to use the `Dispatcher` property of some UI object. If none is accessible to you, you can use `Application.Current`.