# Why leaps exception: "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this"?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Why leaps exception in the load method? If it is to make simultaneous , everything works well . 
Tell me, please , what is the problem and how to fix it ?

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            private readonly List<string> _listImageUri;
            private int _currentIndex;
            private ImageSource _currentImage;
            public ObservableCollection<Image> CustomControls { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Image>();
            public MainViewModel()
            {
                _listImageUri = new List<string>();
                Load("путь к папке");
            }

            private async void Load(string s)
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    foreach (var fileInfo in new DirectoryInfo(s).GetFiles())
                    {
                        _listImageUri.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
                        Image img = new Image(); // exception
                        img.Height = 100;
                        img.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                        img.Width = 100;
                        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                        bmp.BeginInit();
                        bmp.UriSource = new Uri(fileInfo.FullName);
                        bmp.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
                        bmp.EndInit();
                        img.Source = bmp;
                        CustomControls.Add(img);
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CustomControls));
                    }
                });
            }
}
```

**Exception**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183622/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this-in-wpf?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329978/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304472/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this?rq=1 etc

Comment: @stijn, I do not understand how to apply it to my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not create `Image` controls in your view model, especially not when you load images asynchronously.

Change your view model to have an ObservableCollection of `ImageSource`:

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { get; set; }
    = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();
```

Then in your load method make sure that adding images to the collection is done in the UI thread. To make the BitmapImages cross-thread accessible, you also have to freeze them:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileInfo.FullName));
bitmap.Freeze();

Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Images.Add(bitmap)));
```

Finally display the images by means of an ItemsControl with an appropriate ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

That said, you may also replace the `ObservableCollection<ImageSource>` by an `ObservableCollection<string>`, which would hold the image file paths. This is possible because WPF provides built-in conversion from `string` (and `Uri`) to `ImageSource`. Consequently, you would then also not need any asynchronous task anymore.

Answer (score -2):

You run your code in a thread. But updating UI components need to run on the WPF UI thread.

So invoke the critical line(s) using Dispatcher.Invoke so that your code is using the UI-Thread